# "I miss or I am missing" meaning I don't have it?

Tags: present-continuous

I also have all the
vinyls and flexis, but **I'm still missing** a few tapes, the really old ones .
I think miss would be better than is missing .

Does Is missing mean that the writer thinks that he is going to find them at the end?

It could take a lot of time but he will find them .
What is the difference between I miss something and I am missing something meaning I dont have it?

Answer (score 4):

> 1: *I'm [still] missing a few tapes*
> I have found *most* of the previously-lost tapes, but a few haven't [yet] been found

> 2: *I miss a few tapes*
> I often think longingly of a few tapes that I no longer have

I'm pretty sure that #1 can carry sense #2 in "Indian English", but that's certainly not true of "mainstream" English.

Unless ***still*** or some equivalent is included, nothing about #1 carries any implications as to whether the "missing" tapes will *ever* be found / replaced. But even if ***still*** is present, that simply implies the speaker is continuing to try and locate the outstanding items (a goal he may never actually achieve).

---

Note - ***missing*** is an [*ergative*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ergative) verb here, in that ***a few tapes*** in #1 is the ***object*** of the verb, but we can recast to make that the ***subject,*** with the same meaning (except in this *particular* case, rephrasing loses the original subject completely)...

> 1a: *A few tapes are still missing*

Comment: Is missing is better when used in the sense of I don't have it that  is what you mean

Comment: Well, logically speaking if you miss something, you don't have it, so 
*There are a few tapes I don't have* is pragmatically entailed by #2 anyway. But the whole point of #2 is to to assert that the *lack* of those tapes is making the speaker feel sad.

Comment: "I'm missing" can have sense 2 in any dialect I can think of. For example, the line "I ain't missing you at all" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9e157Ner90), from a song by a Brit but which had great success in the US.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I wouldn't even dignify "I ain't missing you at all"  with the label "dialect". With apologies to any AAVE speakers who might get exercised (hardly relevant here, since it's from a *Brit*) I'd say it's just non-standard / substandard English. I don't deny that *at the absolute margins*, a competent native Anglophone might feasibly say ***I'm missing you*** (though virtually *never* uncontracted ***I am missing you***) on the phone to her absent boyfriend, but people who want to learn English should stick with the default phrasing for that context: ***I miss you***.